# owasp zap how to check vulnerabilities of post request

Tags: java, spring, owasp, zap

I have to check if my endpoint REST POST have or not some vulnerabilities.

I'm using **owasp zap** for the first time.

If I try to **check my endpoint that is a REST POST** just inserting the url in the form on owasp zap, it gives me an **error 405**.

So how can I check this kind of request?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The ZAP Quick Scan is just that, a quick scan :)
You have various options:

- If you have an Swagger / OpenAPI definition then import that: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/openapi-support/
- If you have any API tests then you can proxy those via ZAP
- Otherwise you can send any requests you like via the Manual Request Editor: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/ui/dialogs/man_req/

To learn more about ZAP have a look at the Getting Started Guide: https://www.zaproxy.org/getting-started/